# Using boost fibonacci_heap

Tags: c++, boost

Using `fibonacci_heap` results in a compilation error:

```
struct Less: public binary_function<Node*, Node*, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const Node*& __x,  Node*& __y) const
        { return __x->time < __y->time; }

};

boost::fibonacci_heap<Node*, Less >*    m_heap;
```

then

```
Less* ls = new Less;
m_heap = new boost::fibonacci_heap<Node*, Less >(1000, (*ls));
```

Any attempt to run `m_heap->push(n)` results in

```
no match for call to ‘(TimeSync::Less) (TimeSync::Node* const&, TimeSync::Node*&)’
UnmanagedUtils/Trading/Simulation/TimeSync.h:50: note: candidates are: bool TimeSync::Less::operator()(const TimeSync::Node*&, TimeSync::Node*&) const
/usr/local/include/boost-1_35/boost/property_map.hpp: In function ‘Reference boost::get(const boost::put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>&, const K&) [with PropertyMap = boost::identity_property_map, Reference = unsigned int, K = TimeSync::Node*]’:
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're doing weird things with memory?  i.e. allocating data on the heap without visible reason.

Comment: I need the Less object to be alive after the scope of this function, but anyway it does not matter, declaring Less as local variable results same

Comment: Also, the method signature of the method the call expects indicates that a const modifier is not in the right place.  Try changing your signature to: `bool operator()(Node* const& __x,  Node*& __y) const`

Comment: If the only reason you need it to be alive is so the heap can continue to own it, it already will, since you pass it a copy.

Comment: did it before:), does not help, not the issue here (regarding the const qualifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the signature to `operator()(Node * const &, Node * const &) const`.

Comment: The `operator()` of your predicate has to take the arguments by const-reference (or by value); that's all. Your original code had non-const references, which can't be bound to by the internal algorithms of the data structure, which presumably pass elements as constant references.

Comment: @RomanNassimov: That said, I would personally just write the operator as `operator()(Node *, Node *) const`. There's no benefit here in passing the pointers by const-reference, since you know that they're very small types.