# boost::fibonacci_heap: Nested define of handle with comparator redefined circular definition errors

Tags: c++, boost, fibonacci-heap

Boost documentation and previous stack overflow both give working examples of how to define custom comparator functions and include handle in the node type of a boost heap. However when I combine both of these features (a custom defined compare function and a handle within the node type) I get errors reporting invalid use of incomplete type of 'struct compare_Node'.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/heap/concepts.html#heap.concepts.mutability

[Using boost fibonacci_heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494744/using-boost-fibonacci-heap)

[Defining compare function for fibonacci heap in boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705894/defining-compare-function-for-fibonacci-heap-in-boost)

[Decrease operation in fibonacci heap, boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466902/decrease-operation-in-fibonacci-heap-boost?rq=1)

Other than predefining both structs of Node and compare_Node I'm not sure to solve the circularity while still holding the handle's safely as a member within the Node struct.

```cpp
#include <boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>

struct compare_Node; //predefine to avoid circular issues
struct Node; //predefine to avoid circular issues

using fib_heap = boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<struct Node*,
    boost::heap::compare<struct compare_Node>>;

// 6-byte struct total
struct Node {
    double value; 

    fib_heap::handle_type* handle; // orig
};

// override for min_heap
struct compare_Node
{
    bool operator() (struct Node* const n1, struct Node* const n2) const
    {
        return n1->value > n2->value;
    }
};

int main() {
    fib_heap heap;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `compare_Node` only with the declaration of `operator()`. Pointers to `Node` don't need `Node` definition. After `Node` definition, you can add the body of `operator()`:

```
struct compare_Node
{
    bool operator() (struct Node* const n1, struct Node* const n2) const;
};

using fib_heap = boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<struct Node*,
    boost::heap::compare<struct compare_Node>>;

// 6-byte struct total
struct Node {
    double value; 

    fib_heap::handle_type* handle; // orig
};

bool compare_Node::operator() (struct Node* const n1, struct Node* const n2) const
{
        return n1->value > n2->value;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/LzIPv3).